# SQL NVL alternative in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, nvl, intersystems-iris

I do have that silly job at work,in which I need to analyse and improve the performance on some stupid 20 years old SQL statements.

One statement uses NVL in the WHERE clause (no wonder why it's slow) but I still have to improve the performance and the data really needs to be the same when returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM TOURHead, TOURFIND, SGNRFIND, TNRHead
WHERE TOURHead.cl = '123'
AND TOURHead.cl = TOURFIND.cl
AND TOURHead.TOURNR = TOURFIND.TOURNR
AND TOURFIND.cl =* SGNRFIND.cl
AND TOURFIND.SGNR    =* SGNRFIND.SGNR
AND TOURFIND.cl = TNRHead.cl
AND NVL(TOURFIND.TNR, SGNRFIND.TNR) = TNRHead.TNR;
```

Really hope someone can help me with this one.

I know that the =* really shouldn't be in use and that JOINS are the proper way to go. Anyways, I have no idea what I can do to get rid of the NVL.

Comment: which datavbase system belngs this query

Comment: Either TNR IS NULL, in which case you need to compare the other one, or TNR IS NOT NULL, and it can be compared directly. This will either lead to an OR in your condition (which doesn't always speed up a query), or you'll have to split the query into two and use UNION. UNION would mean execute it twice and sort the result. That's expensive too. But you can try and measure.

Comment: You'd need to at least tell us the *actual* database system or we can't help you.

Comment: I'd start by re-writing the query using ANSI SQL JOIN syntax - so that it's much easier to understand and experiment with the join types. The join syntax it's currently using has been outdated for 30+ years

Comment: `I know that the =* really shouldn't be in use and that JOINS are the proper way to go.` Then fix it!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isnull as alternative of NVL.

AND ISNULL(TOURFIND.TNR, SGNRFIND.TNR) = TNRHead.TNR;

and kindly check proper index is available for both this column.